# How do I get V1 (APIVersion 2018-04-16) scheduled query log alert details using Get-AzScheduledQueryRule

Tags: azure-powershell

I am using the PowerShell command Get-AzScheduledQueryRule to get details of the various log based alerts we have deployed within Azure. This command works fine for V2 based log alerts and I am able to view details such as Action Custom Properties.
The problem I have is with older V1 log based alerts created using API Version 2018-04-16, as although I am able to see certain alert details such as name, description etc. I cannot see the json payload details which is the information I need.

I have tried other PowerShell commands, get-azalert but that is for legacy classic alerts and not the ones I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Get-AzScheduledQueryRule` command is used to manage V2 log alerts in Azure. It is incompatible with older V1 log alerts created with API Version 2018-04-16.

You must use the `REST API` to view the JSON payload details of older V1 log alerts. You can use the `REST API` to perform log search queries in Log Analytics and retrieve the `JSON` payload details of older V1 log alerts.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/scheduledqueryrule-2018-04-16/scheduled-query-rules/get?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0).

```bash
Request: GET 
URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourcegroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules/test-rule?api-version=2018-04-16
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Alternatively***, you can use `get-AZresource` command with the `resourceID` and `API version` parameters to retrieve any Azure resource information.

I provided the below command with the `query alert rule resourceID` and retrieved the expected results.

```
 Get-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Insights/scheduledqueryrules/test-rule -ApiVersion "2018-04-16"
```

[image]

***AzCLI:***

*You can also use the below approach using Azure CLI as given.*

```bash
az rest --method get --url /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/workspace/alertsversion?api-version=2017-04-26-preview
```

[image]